# Rspec, array with FactoryGirl objects always return nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, rspec

When I test `wish` objects separately it works:

```
before do
  @wish1 = FactoryGirl.create(:wish)
  @wish2 = FactoryGirl.create(:wish)
  @wish3 = FactoryGirl.create(:wish)
  visit wishes_path
end

it { should have_link(@wish1.destination)}
it { should have_link(@wish2.destination)}
it { should have_link(@wish3.destination)}
```

But when I try it with array, and loop through with `each`, it returns nil.

```
[@wish1, @wish2, @wish3].each do |w|
   it { should have_link(w.destination)}
end
```

results

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `destination' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there any way to improve this test? My page should have many links of Wishes and most of them are different, so there will be a lot of duplicates. But I can't make it simpler.

Comment: outside the context of the tests, the instance variables are not defined. So your array is actually `[nil, nil, nil]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let!(:wishes) { FactoryGirl.create_list(:wish, 3) }

it 'pages includes all whishes links' do
  visit wishes_path
  wishes.each do |wish|
    page.should have_link(wish.destination)
  end
end
```